# Class Average with Scanners

Tags: java, methods, average

I'm having a problem with the following code. I need the application to ask the user for the number of students and then ask for each grade. With this I have to find the average. This is my code so far, I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment6 
{
    public static int students;
    public static int grade;
    public static int avg;
    public static int obtainStudents(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many students");
        students = input.nextInt();
        return students;
        }

    public static double obtainGrade(int students){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter Grade");
            grade = input.nextInt();
            grade+=grade;

        return grade;
    }
    public static double calculateClassAverage(){
        for(int i = 0; i<students; ++i){
            obtainGrade(students);
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
        avg = grade / students;
    return avg;
    }


public static void main (String [] Args){
    obtainStudents();
    calculateClassAverage();
    System.out.println(avg);

}

}
```

Comment: What is the current behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies where you total all of the grades to find the average.

```
public static double obtainGrade(int students){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Grade");
        //sets grade to input wiping all previous inputs
        grade = input.nextInt();
        //adds grade to itself again
        grade+=grade;

    return grade;
}
```

You should do something like this

```
public static int totalGrade

public static double obtainGrade(int students){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Grade");
        grade = input.nextInt();
        totalGrade+=grade;

    return grade;
}

avg = totalGrade/students;
```

Comment: Worked out perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`grade = input.nextInt()` replaces the accumulated total.
`grade+=grade` then doubles the value.

**Result:**
`grade` is always equal to double the value of last entered grade.
`avg = grade / students` then means `avg = 2 * lastGrade / studentCount`.